# SQL Server query to select all columns of a certain type and also show its max values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, dynamic-sql, sql-function

I am using SQL Server 2012.

The first part of my query is already answered in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9678260/find-all-columns-of-a-certain-type-in-all-tables-in-a-sql-server-database). But I also want a second column that will show the corresponding maximum value of that column in its corresponding table.

I have tried this approach: use a function that takes in table name and column name as parameter and return the max value. But it is illegal to use dynamic SQL from a function. Moreover, i cannot seem to call a function from within a SELECT query.

I have also tried using stored procedure, but i cannot figure out how to call it and use it. Please suggest alternative ways to achieve this.

I am new to SQL Server.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest solution would be stored procedure. As far as I know:

- Dynamic SQL can't be placed in functions
- Dynamic SQL can't be place in OPENROWSET

I addition, if you write such procedure:

- Beware of names containing spaces, qoutes (SQL injection possible)
- MAX(column) on non-Indexed columns would require full scan (can be very slow)
- Table and column names can be duplicated (placed in differend schemas)

Id duplicates and performance is not a problem, take a look at the following snippet:

```
CREATE PROC FindMaxColumnValues
    @type sysname  = '%',
    @table sysname = '%'
AS
DECLARE @result TABLE (TableName sysname, ColumnName sysname, MaxValue NVARCHAR(MAX))

DECLARE @tab sysname
DECLARE @col sysname
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
  SELECT TABLE_NAME TableName, COLUMN_NAME [Column Name]
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE DATA_TYPE LIKE @type and TABLE_NAME LIKE @table

OPEN cur

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @tab, @col
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX) = 'SELECT '+QUOTENAME(@tab,'''')+' [TableName], '+QUOTENAME(@col, '''')+' [ColumnName], MAX('+QUOTENAME(@col)+') FROM '+QUOTENAME(@tab)
    INSERT INTO @result EXEC(@sql)
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @tab, @col
END

CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur

SELECT * FROM @result
```

**Samples:**

```
--MAX of INT's
EXEC FindMaxColumnValues 'INT'
--MAX of INT's in tables matching 'TestTab%'
EXEC FindMaxColumnValues 'INT', 'TestTab%'
--MAX of ALL columns
EXEC FindMaxColumnValues
```

**Results:**

```
TableName   ColumnName   MaxValue
IdNameTest  ID           2
TestTable   ID           5
TestTable   Number       3

TableName   ColumnName   MaxValue
TestTable   ID           5
TestTable   Number       3

TableName       ColumnName   MaxValue
UpdateHistory   UpdateTime   2016-07-14 12:21:37.00
IdNameTest      ID           2
IdNameTest      Name         T2
TestTable       ID           5
TestTable       Name         F
TestTable       Number       3
```

Comment: Dyl the 3 points that you mentioned in the "in addition" section is really helpful. The database that i have does indeed have **same table names and column names but in different schemas**. There are many entries so i am worried about using MAX. And injection is always a concern but all nomenclature in my setup has no space or other special characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below SP and enhance it per your Need,

```
CRETE PROCEDURE Getmaxtablecolval
AS
  BEGIN
      CREATE TABLE #t
        (
           tablename  VARCHAR(50),
           columnname VARCHAR(50),
           id         INT,
           counts     INT
        )

      INSERT INTO #t
      SELECT table_name  [Table Name],
             column_name [Column Name],
             NULL,
             NULL
      FROM   information_schema.columns
      WHERE  data_type = 'INT'

      BEGIN TRAN

      DECLARE @id INT

      SET @id = 0

      UPDATE #t
      SET    @id = id = @id + 1

      COMMIT TRAN

      DECLARE @RowCount INT

      SET @RowCount = (SELECT Count(0)
                       FROM   #t)

      DECLARE @I INT

      SET @I = 1

      DECLARE @Counter INT
      DECLARE @TName VARCHAR(50)
      DECLARE @CName VARCHAR(50)
      DECLARE @DynamicSQL AS VARCHAR(500)

      WHILE ( @I <= @RowCount )
        BEGIN
            SELECT @TName = tablename
            FROM   #t
            WHERE  id = @I

            SELECT @CName = columnname
            FROM   #t
            WHERE  id = @I

            SET @DynamicSQL = 'Update #T Set Counts = '
                              + '(Select ISNull(Max(' + @CName + '), 0) From '
                              + @TName + ') Where Id = '
                              + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @I)

            --PRINT @DynamicSQL
            EXEC (@DynamicSQL)

            SET @I = @I + 1
        END

      SELECT *
      FROM   #t
  END

go

Getmaxtablecolval
```

Comment: Ok! So you're using a temporary table! Thats a nice approach! But you are first creating the table with the column and table names, and then you are running a loop to populate the maximum values. Is there a way to do it **at one go**? Or without a temporary table?

Comment: Hmm we need a (temp) table in order to create a dynamic query as the result doesn't belongs to a single table.Since we need to loop thru, we can't create it **at one go**. Feel free to drop a message for further queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a procedure out of this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GET_COLUMNS_WITH_MAX_VALUE

    @COLUMN_TYPE NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- DUMMY VARIABLE TO COPY STRUCTURE TO TEMP
        DECLARE @DUMMY TABLE
    (
        TABLE_NAME NVARCHAR(50),
        COLUMN_NAME NVARCHAR(50),
        MAX_VALUE NVARCHAR(MAX)
    )

    -- CREATE TEMP TABLE FOR DYNAMIC SQL
    SELECT TOP 0 * INTO #TABLE FROM @DUMMY

    INSERT INTO #TABLE
    (TABLE_NAME,  COLUMN_NAME)
    SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
    FROM information_schema.columns where data_type = @COLUMN_TYPE

    DECLARE @TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(50) -- database name  
    DECLARE @COLUMN_NAME VARCHAR(256) -- path for backup files  

    DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
    SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME 
    FROM #TABLE

    OPEN db_cursor   
    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @TABLE_NAME, @COLUMN_NAME 

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
    BEGIN   

    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) =  'UPDATE #TABLE SET MAX_VALUE = (SELECT MAX([' + @COLUMN_NAME + ']) FROM [' + @TABLE_NAME + ']) '
                                 + 'WHERE [COLUMN_NAME] = ''' + @COLUMN_NAME + ''' AND TABLE_NAME = ''' + @TABLE_NAME  + '''';
    PRINT @SQL
    EXEC (@SQL)

    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @TABLE_NAME, @COLUMN_NAME 

    END   

    CLOSE db_cursor   
    DEALLOCATE db_cursor


    SELECT * FROM #TABLE

    DROP TABLE #TABLE

END
GO
```

**Usage:**

```
EXEC GET_COLUMNS_WITH_MAX_VALUE 'INT'
```

**Results:**

```
TABLE1      ID      50
TABLE2      ID      100
TABLE3      CarID       20  
TABLE4      StudentID   30
```

Comment: Nice! Similar approach as @Lucky. But i like the fact that you have used a cursor. Also, its sweet that the datatype can be passed as a parameter to the stored procedure. :) Once again, can it be done in one go and without a temporary table?

Comment: @MercuryX It is not possible to construct a dynamic query based on values of a row in a single query. `SELECT MAX(ColumName)` must be compiled to a valid column name. It can't be based on the value of another column.

Comment: Yes, thats true indeed! I think i like your answer :)