# Find all columns of type nvarchar(max) in all tables in a SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I found this question on stackoverflow that almost answers my question: [Find all columns of a certain type in all tables in a SQL Server database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9678260/find-all-columns-of-a-certain-type-in-all-tables-in-a-sql-server-database)

However I need to find all fields of type nvarchar(max) specifically. If I try this:

```
SELECT table_name [Table Name], column_name [Column Name]
FROM information_schema.columns where data_type = 'nvarchar(max)'
```

It doesn't work and nothing is returned. If I try this:

```
SELECT table_name [Table Name], column_name [Column Name]
FROM information_schema.columns where data_type = 'nvarchar'
```

It works but there are hundreds of results and I only care about fields of max size. How do I select all nvarchar(max) fields specifically?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The `character_maximum_length` will be -1 for `max`.

```
select 
    table_name as [Table Name]
  , column_name as [Column Name]
from information_schema.columns 
where data_type = 'nvarchar' 
  and character_maximum_length=-1
```

Comment: what if I would also print the max LEN of each nvarchar field?

Comment: @markzzz you would include `character_maximum_length` in the `select` and remove it from the `where`.

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE DATA_TYPE = 'nvarchar' AND CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH = -1
```

Comment: I think you're missing an `AND` between `'nvarchar'` and `CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH`